# Sharepoint List - Calculating weekdays between two dates ignoring blanks (Project Registration Date to Gate 0)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

Hi I have a calculated column that counts me no. of weekdays

```
=(DATEDIF([Registration],[Gate 0],"D"))-INT(DATEDIF([Registration],[Gate 0],"D")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([Gate 0])-WEEKDAY([Registration]))<0,2,0)+1
```

HOWEVER, a Gate 0 date may not be filled (as the gate 0 has not been reached yet), and I get a NUM! or Name? error. I NEED NUM to be blank or 0 in Reg-G0 calculated column. I have been trying lots of code with no success.

Example data

| Project ID | Registration | Gate 0 | Reg-G0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13234 | 19/02/2022 | 30/10/2022 | 180 |
| 44954 | 18/05/2022 |  | #NUM! |
| 69543 | 14/03/2021 | 23/05/2021 | 50 |
| 56456 | 25/03/2021 | 25/03/2023 | 522 |
| 44368 | 14/03/2021 | 14/06/2025 | 1110 |

I NEED NUM to be blank or 0.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, does my answer below help you in any way? If yes, please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Gate 0]),0,(DATEDIF([Registration],[Gate 0],"D"))-INT(DATEDIF([Registration],[Gate 0],"D")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([Gate 0])-WEEKDAY([Registration]))<0,2,0)+1)
```

It will return 0 if `[Gate 0]` column is empty.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint calculated column functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)